# What are the steps that lead to this answer with limits?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I am doing the Ratio test to determine the convergence of a function, however I do not know how do you arrive to this result the teacher just assumed we already knew how to do it, but I don't. What are the steps that lead to this ?

$$Lim_{n->\infty}[\frac{(-10)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\times\frac{n!}{(-10)^n}]=Lim_{n->\infty}[\frac{-10n!}{(n+1)!}]$$

Comment: Are you asking that how to reach RHS from LHS?

Comment: Umm, can you simplify a fraction $a^{n+1}/a^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to expand @zipirovich's comment into a full answer, since as far as I can tell that's the only logical interpretation of the question.

The simplification, while it may look difficult at first glance is a rather simple algebraic simplification:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left [ \frac{\left (-10\right )^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\times \frac{n!}{\left (-10\right )^n}\right ]$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left [ \frac{(-10)\left (-10\right )^n}{\left (-10\right )^n}\times \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\right ]$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left [\frac{-10n!}{(n+1)!}\right ]$$
This can further be simplified to:
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{-10}{n+1}$$

Let me know if this answers your question, if not I will remove this answer.